# Why microwaves used in satellite communications?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, earth, atmospheric-science

I've been reading recently that:-

1. EM waves with a shorter wavelength have shorter range in air/other medium
2. Microwaves are used in satellite communications over radio waves.

This doesn't make sense to me as microwaves have a shorter wavelength than radio waves and hence, should have a shorter range than radiowaves-so should NOT be used over radio waves.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this question?No answers yet...

Comment: see here  https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-microwaves-for-satellite-communications

Comment: This doesn't answer the question set

Comment: Why are microwaves used instead of radio waves when they supposedly have a smaller range?

Comment: Have you forgotten the ionosphere which is between the satellites and the earth? The ionosphere reflects radio waves so that we can get them on the surface, but from the satellite it will mainly reflect them back to space. You need something that will penetrate the ionosphere, does not need too large antennas, and is easy technologically in general

Comment: So-radio waves have a longer range than microwaves BUT can't penetrate the ionosphere-so microwaves are used.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: yes, you need penetration of ionosphere for  clear communication.

Comment: So this is just an anomaly-for general cases where range is paramount(no ionosphere)-we will use radiowaves?

Comment: It depends if you want to spend power in general radiation, microwaves can be better directed better

Comment: Just for range?(regardless of other factors)

Comment: radio waves are good  for sending signals long distances large ranges  economically

Comment: Microwaves *are* radio waves.

Answer (score 3):

there are (at least) three reasons, as follows.

1) microwaves can make it through the ionosphere with a minimum of attenuation, whereas lower frequencies tend instead to either bounce off it and return to earth or be absorbed and dissipated by the ionosphere,

2) a high-gain microwave antenna can be easily made small enough to fit on a satellite, and

3) microwaves can be readily formed into a directional beam which facilitates long-distance communication with a minimum of power.

Per Martin Beckett, another reason is that microwave frequencies allow high bandwidth, which means high data transmission rates.

Comment: And bandwidth ?